# Создание запросов в базе данных

Tags: sql, база-данных

**Есть база данных:**
[image: Схема_данных]
**И дано 3 отчета (или запроса):**

1) Отчет за период по выполненным заказам (код заказа, стоимость заказа, сумма фактической оплаты).

2) Отчет по видам заказа за период (вид заказ, количество заказов за период, сумма стоимостей выполненных заказов этого вида за период)

3) Отчет по эффективности сотрудников за период (ФИО сотрудника, количество выполненных этим сотрудником заказов за период, сумма оплаты выполненных этим сотрудников заказов за период)

Я чайник полнейший, то что пробовал, казалось бредом (ничего не получалось), поэтому прошу помощи у вас.
Хотя бы **пните** в правильное направление, что б я сам подумал

Comment: Если с английским хорошо, то https://sqlbolt.com/

Comment: Если с английским не очень, то http://www.sql-ex.ru/